# Why do I have to use a high order function as first argument in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, throttling, debouncing

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<button class="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
const clickMe = document.querySelector('.clickMe');

const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timeoutId;
  return function(...args) {
    if(timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    } 
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        fn(...args)
      }, delay)
  }
}

clickMe.addEventListener('click', debounce((e) => {
  console.log('clicked')
}, 300));
```

On this line:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        fn(...args)
      }, delay)
```

I've tried to pass the `fn(...args)` directly in like this:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(fn(...args), delay)
```

But that doesn't work. Why is that we need a higher order function that returns that inner function here?

Comment: Because it is a callback. A function that will be executed after the timeout. When you call the function like `fn(...args)` you are eagerly forcing evaluation so there is no point of in setting a timeout because the function has already run at that point

Comment: It's not a higher-order function, it doesn't *return* the inner function. It just *calls*  the `fn`.

Comment: Assisting *Bergi* ... a [*higher order function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function#example_return_a_function) is a functions which returns a function, whereas a function which serves e.g. as an argument to another function is called a [*first class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function) citizen. Everything else already was clarified by *Lakshya Thakur*.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need that wrapping up of your function call inside another anonymous function. You can make use of the following syntax :-

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(func, delay,...args);
```

Also that's not a **higher order function**. A **higher order function** can either accept a function as argument or return a function or do both. You can say `setTimeout` is a **higher order function**.

For more info on this syntax, look up - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout